# Google Play Store - App Unlisting ( Hiding the app from Play store search )

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, app-distribution

I created a hybrid mobile app using React Native and submitted the Android app for Google PlayStore review which was approved with out any issues . Apple rejected our app saying we need to distribute the app with " [Unlisted App Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/)" method , now we want to check If there is any way to "unlist " our Android app also from Google Play store .

"Unlisted " app distribution refers to hiding the app from App Store / Play Store search results or  App Categories . These apps will be accessed through the direct link only .

Thanks in advance for your response

There is an option in Apple Developer portal for [unlisted app distribution](https://developer.apple.com/support/unlisted-app-distribution/) , I am looking for the similar experience in the Google Play store.

Comment: Android don't have an option for Unlisted Distribution . We somehow convinced Apple to publish our app as a Public app .